# Is there a list of all the required spirits I need to progress in World of Light?

Tags: super-smash-bros-ultimate

My inventory now has a ton of spirits, and a lot of these are duplicates in terms of abilities.  For example, I have numerous **Punch Attack ↑** support spirits, and I can see the value in stacking them, but for spirits like **Immune to Poison/Lava/Sleep** it seems pointless to bother hoarding multiple of the same.

That said, there seems to be a required list of spirits I need? to progress through World of Light. As of 75% right now, I've cleared most but not all, and still have a few obscured sections.  I'd like to know which spirits are required to progress in the story so I can get rid of duplicates that aren't those spirits.

At least from what I can tell so far, I need:

- Bomberman, for rock demolition
- Cyrus & Reese, for bridge building
- Lapras, for the water surfing section SE
- Kapp'n, for the boat/lake section SW
- Hal Emmerich, to get into the bunker SW
- Pico, for the F-Zero racing circuit
- Bus Dude (can't find the name), for the Bus route between the Town W and the city center

Do I need any more?

Comment: Some of the obstacles can be cleared with multiple spirits. E.g. bridges can be built by Bord & Cord & Barst, rocks can be demolished with Mouser.

Comment: Also keep in mind spirits that have the same effect can still be useful since you get bonuses for using spirits from the same game series.

Comment: @Malco This is the first I'm hearing about this. What kind of bonuses are they?

Comment: @senpai If the spirit is from the same series as your fighter they get a 1.1x multiplier to attk, def, power stats. Probably worth a full question. https://www.reddit.com/r/smashbros/comments/a5fece/spirits_mode_damage_formula_why_power_is/

Answer (score 2):

You need Kamek,Viridi, or Kammy Koopa to make mushrooms grow. The mushrooms are west from the starting point. You also need the Great Zapfish to restore the power plant.  Alfonzo & Engineer Link will be needed to start a train. You need Viridi to grow a magic bean sprout. You will need Slippy toad to be a pilot. That's all I know.